# Select the surrounding tag in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have $(this) pointing at my input box but cannot seem to reference the surrounding span to add a red border.

```
<span id="hdr-su_name" class="eforminput">
    <input type="text" size="30" id="su_name" name="su_name">
</span>
```

I have tried this but does not work:

```
$(this).parent().css({'border-color':'1px solid #ff0000'});
```

Any help much appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this).parent().css({'border':'1px solid #ff0000'});
```